# How can I add UpdatePanels to my gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have a gridview with some textboxes and buttons inside the gridview. I want to use updatepanels when the buttons are clicked so that only one textbox is refreshed instead of the whole page. I tried to add my ScriptManager and UpdatePanel inside my gridview but I get errors saying the tags aren't recognized.

I've looked elsewhere on SO for solutions and others have said to place the whole gridview in an UpdatePanel. However, I don't want the whole grid to be updated (it's pretty lengthy). Is it possible to have individual UpdatePanels in my gridview?

**EDIT:**

Here is some code to go along with my question:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="PCalendar" EventName="SelectedChange" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QS">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server" Text=' <%#Bind("PDate") %>' OnTextChanged="SetTextBox" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:ImageButton ID="PButton" runat="server" OnClick="ShowCalendar" ImageUrl="../images/calendarIcon.jpg" />
                      <asp:Calendar ID="PCalendar" runat="server" Visible="false" OnSelectionChanged="SetDate" ></asp:Calendar>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
           </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: So the code you have. You don't want to put the updatepanels within the grid.. you want to put the grid within the update panels. If you show your code, it will be much easier to show you how it's done.

Comment: Can you post some amount of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what it's going to sorta look like. Once you post your code, it will be easier to see how close you are and how to help you properly. But this is the general idea.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="buttonOneID" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="buttonTwoID" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                    <Columns>
                        //columns code here
                   </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I think you need to set the `UpdateMode`of UpdatePanel to `Conditional`. Otherwise the UpdatePanel will update it's content on each Postback.

Comment: It shouldn't. But it would depend on how he has it set it. The above will only update the panel if buttonOneID is Update or something of that sort. This is the basic structure I use for my gridviews and update panels and have had no issues.

Comment: Are you sure? `UpdateMode="Always"` is the default value. See this msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. Yes, on every post back, the content within the gridview will be refreshed unless UpdateMode is set to conditional. Good catch.

Comment: This is the basic idea of what I would need. However, placing the Triggers out if the contentTemplate when the buttons are located inside the grid is causing a problem. I get an error saying that the ControlID for the button could not be found. Should I have the triggers placed somewhere else?

Comment: If the buttons are in the grid, you don't need the triggers. Remove the triggers and see if that works.

Comment: yep, I left out the triggers and it works fine. thanks